# WebSphere Installation Error

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I am trying to install web Sphere Server trail version in my machine. 
I am able install the IBM Installation Manager 1.8.
then I am trying to install IBM WAS 8.5.5 ND then I am getting the below error

Error:

```
The com.ibm.websphere.NDTRIAL.v85 package specified in the C:\wasnd\NDTRIAL.agent.installer.win32.win32.x86_64\install.xml file cannot be found.
The com.ibm.websphere.IBMJAVA.v70 package specified in the C:\wasnd\NDTRIAL.agent.installer.win32.win32.x86_64\install.xml file cannot be found.
The com.ibm.websphere.liberty.IBMJAVA.v70 package specified in the C:\wasnd\NDTRIAL.agent.installer.win32.win32.x86_64\install.xml file cannot be found.
The com.ibm.websphere.IHSILAN.v85 package specified in the C:\wasnd\NDTRIAL.agent.installer.win32.win32.x86_64\install.xml file cannot be found.
The com.ibm.websphere.APPCLIENTILAN.v85 package specified in the C:\wasnd\NDTRIAL.agent.installer.win32.win32.x86_64\install.xml file cannot be found.
The com.ibm.websphere.NDDMZTRIAL.v85 package specified in the C:\wasnd\NDTRIAL.agent.installer.win32.win32.x86_64\install.xml file cannot be found.
The com.ibm.websphere.PLGILAN.v85 package specified in the C:\wasnd\NDTRIAL.agent.installer.win32.win32.x86_64\install.xml file cannot be found.
The com.ibm.websphere.WCTILAN.v85 package specified in the C:\wasnd\NDTRIAL.agent.installer.win32.win32.x86_64\install.xml file cannot be found.
The com.ibm.websphere.W2MTKILAN.v11 package specified in the C:\wasnd\NDTRIAL.agent.installer.win32.win32.x86_64\install.xml file cannot be found.
The com.ibm.websphere.EDGELBIPV4IPV6TRIAL.v85 package specified in the C:\wasnd\NDTRIAL.agent.installer.win32.win32.x86_64\install.xml file cannot be found.
The com.ibm.websphere.PLUGCLIENTILAN.v85 package specified in the C:\wasnd\NDTRIAL.agent.installer.win32.win32.x86_64\install.xml file cannot be found.
The com.ibm.websphere.liberty.NDTRIAL.v85 package specified in the C:\wasnd\NDTRIAL.agent.installer.win32.win32.x86_64\install.xml file cannot be found.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an indication that there is a connection issue with the repositories that you were trying to access to install WebSphere Application Server trial.  Installation Manager was trying to access IBM's live repositories for the trial offerings.

Check your connection and retry. If you are behind a firewall, you may need to configure Installation Manager to use a proxy server.